# Code for Day of Week to repeat for each name

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Table with several rows of data that get submitted by employees.

One of the columns that I have is for the Day of the week which the employee has to enter.
In order for the other half of the system to work properly, I require a submission for each day of the week. I already have the code to add a new row if there are submissions missing.

I am hoping someone can help me with a way to check what days haven't be submitted for each employee, and add it to the column.

```
 Set nRow = A.ListRows.Add
With nRow
  .Range(1) = "Name"
  .Range(2) = ""
  .Range(3) = "Date"
  .Range(4) = ""
  .Range(5) = ""
  .Range(6) = ""
  .Range(7) = ""
  .Range(8) = ""
  .Range(9) = ""
  .Range(10) = ""
  .Range(11) = "N"
  .Range(12) = "Y"
  .Range(13) = "Day Of Week goes here"
  .Range(14) = ""
  .Range(15) = ""
  .Range(16) = ""
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

`Format(date,"dddd")` will return todays day of week - e.g. "Tuesday" for 3.5.2022.

`Format(date, "ddd")` will return the abbreviation.

The name itself depends on the current language settings.

If you want to use a different date than today just replace 'date' with your date-variable.

Comment: thank you for that. i problem i have is that the submissions are not checked each day, only on a monday. so i need to be able to tell excel that friday was missed, and insert it

Comment: That's a different question. Please create a new one on SO describing what you really want to achieve. Reading [ask] and [repro] could help you to write a good question.